# python character in string checking and printing

Tags: python

This is a noob question asked by a noob. I need to create a function to check whether or no all the character in the string can be found in 'scraps', if true, just print out the whole string once, else, print the error message below. I am sure the real solution is pretty simple but at the moment I feel like I am solving calculus problem with grade school math. please advise. thanks~

def fix_it(scraps, recycled):

The function should be able to produce:

print fix_it('AbCdEfG', 'AhK') ==> "Give me something that's not useless next time."

print fix_it('AbCdEfG', 'CdE') ==> 'CdE'

Comment: It sounds like you should look into the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: I know how to print a = "astring"

for i in a:
    print i,  and I even tried to bring the string down into a list by list(astring), then use a for loop to go over scraps, but what I am having trouble with, is to only print out the string once, if all characters are found.

Comment: It's also not clear whether `'CGdE'` would work, or only `'CdE'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def fix_it(scraps, recycled):
    for i in recycled:
        if i not in scraps:
            return "give me something useful"
    return recycled

print fix_it('AbCdEfG', 'AhK')
print fix_it('AbCdEfG', 'CdE')
```

output is:

```
python test.py
give me something useful
CdE
```

Comment: jez...looking back at my failed code, I overcomplicated the process so much. Thanks a lot man~

Comment: No problem.  It can get even smaller, but this is more clear. .  If the answer works for you, would you mind checking the 'accepted answer' check mark.  I need a few more reputation :-)

Comment: @Leorczhu, note that this function would return success for something like `'GECdEEEE'`. I don't know whether you want that or not.

Comment: Its fine Tigerhawk, the purpose of the function is solely focus on checking to see if there are usable characters in the scraps, regardless of the counts.